# How do I compare my username and password with what i got from JSON server with axios.get

Tags: javascript, json, oop, json-server

Im trying to build a login page using json server as database. So, I collect the username and password. I then use axios.get to retrieve all my users and then i tried looping through each object to see anyone that matches. However, it doesnt work. Here is what my db.json looks like

```
{
"users": [
{
      "fullName": "Layoola",
      "email": "ola@yahoo.com",
      "password": "password",
      "phone": "08067721111",
      "id": 6
}]
}
```

And here is what my function looks like

```
<script src="axios.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function () {
              document.getElementById('loginButton').onclick = function () {
                var userEmail = document.getElementById('loginEmail').value;
                var userPassword = document.getElementById('loginPassword').value;
                axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
                  .then(function (response) {
                      let request = response;

                    let userExist =false;
                    for (let i = 0; i < request.length; i++){
                        if(request[i].email == userEmail && request[i].password == userPassword) {
                            let userEmail = true;
                            window.location.href("http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html");
                        }
                }
                    if(userExist == true) {
                    window.location.href("http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html");
                    } else {
                        window.location.href("http://127.0.0.1:5500/register.html");
                    }
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    window.location.href("http://127.0.0.1:5500/about-us.html");
                  });
              };
            })();
```

However.. I keep getting redirected to register. This means i successfully got the results but couldnt find what i was looking for even though it was clearly there.When i put alert(userEmail) in the function, I got what i put in. Meaning the post is being sent. I even only checked the email only and still failed.
P.S. This is for development purposes only. I know i need to encrypt. etc.

Comment: don't store passwords in plain text, especially on publicly accessible endpoint

Comment: doesn't axios wrap response data in a data property? Could you try to access your users collection via request.data

Comment: Read till end.. The last P.S

Comment: @DavidHölkeskamp
How?

Comment: Im new to JS and OODB

Comment: Hi, 

You never update the  var `userExist`... still always `false` even if email or pwd is right. 

`for (...){
                        if(...) {
                            userExist= true; //update the userExist boolean
                            window.location.href("http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html");
                        }
                }
`

Comment: window.location.href ->  [returns the href (URL) of the current page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp). Use [window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) = "http://my-url.com"

Comment: Thanks. Still didnt work

Comment: @OlaiwolaAyoola an axios response is an object containing a property called data, which acts like a container for your response data. If your server sends back any data its accessible by doing response.data. In your case you could try to change the line  let request = response to let request = response.data. 
https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema